# Software Updater complains about free space on `/boot`, `apt` on terminal doesn't

Tags: boot, apt, updates, update-manager

When trying to use the graphical application `Software Updater` on my raspi running Ubuntu Mate 16.04, I for about 10 days now receive an error message titled "Not enough free disk space" which says:

> The upgrade needs a total of 48.2 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 1,982 k of disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.

According to `df -h`, I currently use 20 MiB on `/boot` and have 45 MiB available. So it's true that I don't have 48.2 MiB available.

`sudo apt-get clean` returns instantly with no output.

`sudo apt autoremove` doesn't find anything to remove.

Now I would find it perfectly understandable that `/boot` has too little space if it weren't for the fact that `sudo apt upgrade` runs through perfectly fine.

When I launch `Software Updater` immediately after I ran `sudo apt upgrade`, it checks for updates and then tells my that my software is up-to-date. But each time there are updates, it complains about the lack of storage space available on `/boot`. Why is this?

Comment: Try restarting your system to see if it changes.

Comment: @George I waited 10 days to post this question to see whether it only occurs for a single update and to see whether restarting helps. It doesn't. Tried it several times.

Comment: You need to either remove some old linux kernels from /boot, or make /boot partition larger. Depending on how your disk is partitioned, you may just need to do a general cleanup of your files.

Comment: @heynnema There are no old kernels on `/boot`: https://pastebin.com/uciGcSq5 Why does `apt upgrade` work?

Comment: Then your general hard disk is full. Show me a screenshot of `gparted`.

Comment: @heynnema https://i.imgur.com/F34VAt4.png

Comment: Make your /boot partition larger.

Comment: @heynnema My question is about understanding why upgrading works on the terminal but not via the GUI. It's not about actually performing the upgrade.

Comment: It generally takes about twice the space necessary because it needs room to decompress the downloaded update files before installation.

Comment: @heynnema Doesn't `apt upgrade` have to do the exact same thing? In fact, doesn't `Software Updater` just call `apt upgrade`?

Comment: I can't tell you the technical differences between the two, I can just say how to fix it. Sorry.